# Issue with query, it wont accept condition

Tags: sql

I have this query here:

```
SELECT formas.*, SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET, SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,SMS_SERVISI.time_added
FROM formas 
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET 
WHERE SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET ='' or SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET is null AND  formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='K' 
ORDER BY formas.id DESC;
```

My issue is, it won't accept the condition:

```
formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='K'
```

It's like it won't recognize it...
I need to show all records whose `formas.sektori='K'`
Could you please tell me if i'm putting it in the wrong place?
I have this condition everywhere, and it works...
Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not using parantheses. When one part of the `OR` condition becomes true, the rest is irrelevant.

```
SELECT formas.*, SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET, SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,SMS_SERVISI.time_added
FROM formas 
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET 
WHERE (SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET ='' or SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET is null) AND  formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='K' 
ORDER BY formas.id DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you very very much :)
you're right... i'm accepting this in a few minutes :)
Thanks again